# Variable names for a Cordova plugin on a Capacitor project

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have installed the plugin cordova-plugin-facebook-connect https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect, as an update for the deprecated cordova-plugin-facebook4 https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook4.

As this is a Cordova plugin, **being installed on a Capacitor project**, I have followed these steps to do that: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/using-cordova-plugins

But this plugin requires variables during installation (--variable x), and this is not possible in Capacitor, so I have followed this guide: https://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-that-require-install-variables-with-capacitor/

Now, the question is, how could I know which variable names should I write on the info.plist file for iOS, and on the strings.xml and AndroidManifest.xml for Android?

Anyone has faced the same problem already?

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are asking which variables you should write on the Info.plist and AndroidManifest.xml. But the joshmorony article you're talking about gives a list of the variables to set and how to set it.

Comment: Thanks @saperlipopette. Unfortunately the joshmorony article uses the old deprecated plugin (cordova plugin facebook 4) in his example, not the one I'm trying to use.

Comment: The plugin you are using is just a fork of `cordova-plugin-facebook-4`, it uses the same variables. You can follow the guide

Comment: When I do the 'ionic cap sync ios' step, I get this error: ArgumentError - Illformed requirement `"$FACEBOOK_IOS_SDK_VERSION"`. I have tried to include this variable in the info.plist file, but still getting the error. Works fine for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of cordova-plugin-facebook-connect. I don't use Capacitor, the apps I work on are all built on Cordova. That being said, it looks like this issue was previously reported in https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/3517, and should've been fixed in Capacitor 2.4.1. Perhaps the issue is that you're using an older version?

Comment: https://github.com/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/issues/52 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/721
Cordova update required, it would seem.